# Google+ button shares number of "+1s" across different domains

Tags: google-plus

I have a Google+ button installed on three different domains which essentially differ only in the TLD part (`example.de`, `example.at`, `example.ch`). It might also be worth noting that the websites themselves are almost identical which means that for every page on one of the websites there is an identical one on other two domains (don't ask me why it was a request made by the agency responsible for SEO).

The problem is whenever I use a +1 button on, lets say, `example.de` homepage it's count number also increases on two other domains although in my +1 profile only the clicked page is displayed. Now if I go to the `example.at` homepage and click the +1 button to remove my +1 it will also be removed from the +1 count number on all the other websites.

As for the technical part of the question I am using the standard non-asynchronous version of the +1 button meaning my code essentially looks like this.

```
<!-- Some code... -->
<div class="g-plusone"></div>
<!-- ... even more code... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">{lang: 'de'}</script>
```

Additionally I don't explicitly set the `href` part for the +1 button on every page but rather let the Google Plus script figure it out by itself. I know its not the recommended approach (its even stated in the Google Plus documentation) however this approach used to work very well from the very beginning and I would like to know what might be the potential reason for it to break suddenly.

Honestly I am clueless. I went through all the available documentation on Google+ with no luck and its almost impossible to find anything about this problem on the web.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention the actual URL or if you have any other metadata set for the pages in question, but one possibility is that the canonical link is set to the same value for all of the pages in question. In this case, Google treats them all as the same for +1 purposes. See https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#target-url for further details.

Comment: The behavior that holodoc is stating sounds like he is following the best practices for both +1 and for search. Curious why someone would want to reverse that? This answer is likely correct, but not necessarily something that you want to do.

If each of those domains surfaced the content in a different language, I could see removing the canonical links because search would point visitors to possibly an incorrect version of the content.

Comment: None of the pages makes use of canonical links because we started making changes in content on `.at` and `.ch` pages. In the meantime we have also begun using `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="" />` designations so we hope that Google will realize that those pages should essentially be treated separately.